# Android function zoomImageFromThum(param1, param2) use a lot of RAM and CPU

Tags: android, image, listview

How avoid the 40% of CPU usage and 70MB of RAM (start with 10MB) when a thumb is touched and the function start?

This is the scenario:
I have a `ListView` that can contains text or image.
The user can take pictures and that pictures are saved to sdcard0 and loaded by path to the relative `ImageView`.
I have some problem with the performance of this.

Adapter that save image or text and put it into a listview:
**PS: i try with the ViewHolder for optimize the listview but i get some problem with the image loading with Picasso so i removed it!**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.evento_list_view_line, null);

    ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.compiti_imageView);
    TextView compito = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.compiti_text);

    Compiti m = getItem(position);

    if(m.getTestoCompito() != null){

        compito.setText(m.getTestoCompito());
        //Invisibile e non presente nel layout
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }else if(m.getPathFoto() != null){
        //load img
        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(m.getPathFoto())
                .resize(200, 200)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(img);
        //Set the tag for retrieve the path of image from listview
        img.setTag(m.getPathFoto());
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see i use the setTag(ImgPath) for retrieve the path from ImageView.

This is how i retrieve touched image if the image is in the `ImageView`:

```
// ListView Item Click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ImageView image_to_zoom = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.compiti_imageView);

            if (image_to_zoom.getDrawable() != null) {

                //Image IN
                String path = image_to_zoom.getTag().toString();
                zoomImageFromThumb(image_to_zoom, path);

            } else {
                //Imane nope
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No photo here!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
```

I found the method `zoomImageFromThumb(image_to_zoom, path);` from google.developer and I made ​​some changes because the original code take images from R.resources and i need to take image from memory (folder Pictures).

My change:

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, String imagePath) {
    // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
    // immediately and proceed with this one.
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
            R.id.expanded_image);
    //expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(imagePath)
            .into(expandedImageView);
```

If i set the path manually without the method getTag() the app load very fast the touched image, but with the method getTag() for retrieve the path of the image the app is very slow to load the zoom of touched image.
Some suggestion or help?

**There is another way for retrieve the path of an image in a ImageView?**

Comment: inside getView method of your Adapter you are inflating xml every time this get view called, please optimize this by using some holder. Since getView method of adapter will get called for each row. You will see significant improvement in the performance And you are retrieving path in a efficient way

Comment: Thank you @dex .
Now i optimize my adapters and see the difference.
But if i write manually the path, the zoom is not slow, so it's possible that the getTag() is a slow method?
If i use the holder and the loading reamains slow, i can use some thread? Or something else?

Comment: why are you setting path using getTag, you could have directly retrieve the image path.

Comment: How?
I see to stackoverflow but i found only the method with using the Tag.
How can i retrieve the image path from an ImageView?